# A term for a concept formed through abstraction and from categorization?

Tags: terminology, generic-term, obscure-terms

For e.g, lets say you take the number 1, 2, 3, 4... etc. From these list of numbers, you can abstract from these ideas the concept of a number. You can't do this if you only know of the number 1, if so, it would be *the* number, rather than *a* number, but I digress.

Lets now say you want to define specific *types* of numbers, like integers, decimals, or primes. This is abstraction though categorization. As you already had the concept of a number, you aren't making an entirely new concept, in and within itself, but categorizing a concept and defining new concepts for those categories, which is part of the main concept.

Furthermore, in the former case, when the concept is formed, you expand your scope, in the former, you are narrowing it down to greater precision. So the two ways in which concepts can be formed should, I feel, be given precise terms.

Comment: I suspect this is a job for Philosophy.SE. But I'm no philosopher.

Comment: a refinement???

Comment: Don't use **for e.g.**. _e.g._ is a Latin abbreviation for _exempli gratia_ which means _for the sake of an example_. It already includes the _for_ in it. You did, after all, post in _English_ :)

Comment: @Robert B, modern times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want *generalization* (1, 2, 3 are numbers), *specialization* (a number is 1), and possibly *subcategorization* (numbers are odd, even, prime).

Comment: I actually ended up going with generalization and categorization :)

Comment: Generalization? What?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a question a developer would ask, and I'll posit that **classification** is perhaps the word.

For instance, in object-oriented programming (OOP), objects from the outside world, such as cars and trucks, can be represented in code; we call these **Classes**. For instance, we can have a `Car` class, and a `Motorcycle` class, both of which might extend from a parent class of `Automobile` that happens to contain a `numberOfWheels` property, and say, `color` or anything else that's common between the two.

This is very similar to your numbers example. In OOP, we'd have a `Double` class (like a decimal), an `Integer` class, an so on, that extends from a `Number` class, which in turn extends from the God-tier object - the most generic of all - `Object`:

[image]

But don't take my word for it:

- **Double**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html
- **Object**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html